# Count in sql query - Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql, count

I have this query to count the total number of accounts, but I keep getting an error message of incorrect syntax.

Is there another way to write this query?

```
string all = "SELECT YYMM, Count(Key) AS CountOfKey FROM tbl_WR WHERE 
  (((Right(Year([purchase date]),2) + right('0'+rtrim(month([purchase date])),2))
                              =[yymm])) GROUP BY YYMM HAVING YYMM>=1101";
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Run the query in SSMS (or http://sqlfiddle.com for the web-lazy) and read the error message(s). Break down the query into parts, until you find out which part is the "Incorrect Syntax". Then fix it and build it up again.

Comment: Also, that is invalid C# (as formatted) and will result in "Newline in constant" or similar. A `""` (string literal) cannot contain an unescaped newline. See `@""` (verbatim string literals) or `"\n"` or simple of single-line strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Count(Key)
```

to

```
Count([Key])
```